# How to repeat tasks every 1 minute in Windows 11 task scheduler?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-task-scheduler, windows-11

I have a C# console application that must be run every minute to check data, therefore I use a task scheduler. However, the time available to repeat the task is limited in the Windows 11 task scheduler.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHScA.png)

The minimum time available for the dropdown is only 5 minutes. Can I add more specific times to repeat tasks?

Comment: I got to ask. What scenario requires a background task process to be kicked off that frequently (once a minute)?  That's starting to into "why don't you just let the process persist and wake up every minute on its own" territory

Comment: I want to save data every minute to a database from a txt file that is downloaded automatically on another system. I consider the application to run automatically and close when it has finished inputting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually edit value in the field:

[image]

[image]

Also you can consider starting the app to run constantly and use "in-process" scheduling (with one of the framework-provided [timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) for example).

Comment: I didn't think it could be edited, this works, thank you. :)